# Finding duration between start and end flags in a data frame column by splitting into two different days if if exceeds one day

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable

I have a dataframe like this :

```
   timestamp           Status
05-01-2020  12:07:08    0
05-01-2020  12:36:05    1
05-01-2020  23:45:02    0
05-01-2020  13:44:33    1
06-01-2020  01:07:08    1
06-01-2020  10:23:05    1
06-01-2020  12:11:08    1
06-01-2020  22:06:12    1
07-01-2020  00:01:05    0
07-01-2020  02:17:09    1
07-01-2020  12:36:05    1
07-01-2020  12:07:08    1
07-01-2020  12:36:05    1
07-01-2020  12:36:05    0
08-01-2020  12:36:05    1
08-01-2020  12:36:05    0
08-01-2020  12:36:05    0
09-01-2020  12:36:05    1
09-01-2020  12:07:08    0
09-01-2020  12:36:05    1
11-01-2020  12:07:08    0
11-01-2020  12:36:05    1
```

I am trying to find the duration between each `1,0` pair. But i my data I can have status coming in any order. I may have 1 and 0 occurring 0ne by one..or I may have many 1s followed by a 0 etc.. I am trying to cut the duration into two if start (1) is on on day and end (0) is on next day provided they are continuous dates (like 1,2,3,4) and there is no 1s in between or there are any number of 1s between 1 and 0.
First occurrence of 1 is like start...and first occurrence of 0 is like end.

I am able to calculate in the straight forward condition if 1 and 0 are on same date. Also if it is on two dates, I am able to calculate the difference between occurrence of 1 and 23:59:59 for first day and similarly from 00:00:00 till occurrence of second day.

Ex: let me have one set of data like this

```
07-01-2020  21:26:05    1
08-01-2020  02:33:45    0
```

These two fall on two different dates. So instead of finding the difference directly I want to cut it into two. So on first day (`07-01-2020`) my duration will be from `21:26:05 to 23:59:59` and on second day it will be from `00:00:00 to 02:33:45`. This should repeat for any number of continuous dates.(like 7,8,9,10 etc)

But If have data like this:

```
07-01-2020  21:26:05    1
08-01-2020  02:33:45    1
09-01-2020  21:26:05    1
11-01-2020  02:33:45    1
```

I have to cut at (because after 9th its 11th so continuity is broken)

```
07-01-2020  21:26:05 to  07-01-2020  23:59:59
08-01-2020  00:00:00 to  08-01-2020  02:33:45
08-01-2020  02:33:45 to  08-01-2020  23:59:59
09-01-2020  00:00:00 to  09-01-2020  21:26:05
09-01-2020  21:26:05 to  09-01-2020  23:59:59
```

conditions like this :

```
07-01-2020  21:26:05    1
07-01-2020  22:33:45    1
07-01-2020  23:31:51    1
07-01-2020  23:48:33    0
07-01-2020  23:57:12    0
```

is same as:

```
 07-01-2020  21:26:05    1
  07-01-2020  23:48:33    0
```

And conditions like this :

```
07-01-2020  21:26:05    1
07-01-2020  22:33:45    1
07-01-2020  23:31:51    1
08-01-2020  03:48:33    0
08-01-2020  03:57:12    0
```

is same as:

```
  07-01-2020  21:26:05   to  07-01-2020  23:59:59
  07-01-2020  00:00:00   to  08-01-2020  03:48:33
```

I tried ifelse condition using in datatable and I was able to do the first split from x to 23:59:59 on the first day. But no other conditions are working.

```
 df[, difference := ifelse((df$Status == 0 & shift(df$Status,type='lag') == 1) & (as.Date(df$timestamp) !=  shift(as.Date(df$timestamp),type = 'lag')),
    as.numeric(df$timestamp - as.POSIXct(paste0(as.Date(timestamp)," ","00:00:00"),tz="UTC"),units='mins'),ifelse((df$Status == 1 & shift(df$Status,type='lead') == 0) & as.Date(df$timestamp) !=  shift(as.Date(df$timestamp),type = 'lead'),as.numeric(as.POSIXct(paste0(as.Date(timestamp)," ","23:59:59"),tz="UTC") - df$timestamp,units='mins'),
    as.numeric(shift(df$timestamp,type = 'lead') -  df$timestamp,units='mins')))]
```

Comment: Hi Victor, I am not clear on your logic or your desired output. You say "I am trying to find the duration" but none of your post shows a duration. Additionally, you say "between each 1,0 pair". Do you mean *all* possible pairs or only successive pairs in time? Could you provide a concrete example of your data and desired output?

Comment: I didnt specifically show the duration.. but in my code i am calculating that only..and regarding 1,0 pair it should be all possible pairs.. but if 1 on one day and 0 is on another day a split should be made in duration finding.. else simple differece.. can you check the code thatvi posted?

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
# Non-daily split: 
df %>% 
  mutate(grp = cumsum(ifelse(ind == 0, 1, 0))) %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  filter(!(duplicated(ind))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(duration = difftime(timestamp, lag(timestamp), units = "hours"))


# Daily split: 
df %>% 
  group_by(grp1 = as.Date(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d")) %>% 
  filter(!duplicated(ind)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(grp = cumsum(ifelse(ind == 0, 1, 0))) %>% 
  group_by(grp, grp1) %>% 
  mutate(duration = difftime(timestamp, lag(timestamp), units = "hours")) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Using the toy data I provided in my answer and looking at the sequence 0-1-1, your answer seems to calculate the time distance between 0 and the **last** 1 instead of the first one?

Comment: Will it split at 12 midnight?

Comment: @VictorJohnzon second one will.

Comment: @VictorJohnzon Please upvote and accept the answer if it does what you require.

Answer (score 0):

Let

```
A = data.frame(timestamp = c(as.POSIXlt("2020-07-01 21:26:05"), 
                             as.POSIXlt("2020-07-02  02:33:45"), 
                             as.POSIXlt("2020-07-02  10:33:45"),
                             as.POSIXlt("2020-07-03  15:33:45"),
                             as.POSIXlt("2020-07-04  02:33:45")),
               ind = as.numeric(c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1) ))

> A
            timestamp ind
1 2020-07-01 21:26:05   0
2 2020-07-02 02:33:45   1
3 2020-07-02 10:33:45   1
4 2020-07-03 15:33:45   0
5 2020-07-04 02:33:45   1
```

be toy data for this example. Then the following code gives you the time distance between the first occurences of successive 0s and 1s.

```
A %>%
  mutate(Diff = ind - lag(ind)) %>% 
  filter(is.na(Diff) | Diff != 0) %>% 
  mutate(Timedist = timestamp - lag(timestamp)) %>%
  select(-Diff)
```

with output

```
            timestamp ind   Timedist
1 2020-07-01 21:26:05   0    NA hours
2 2020-07-02 02:33:45   1   5.1 hours
3 2020-07-03 15:33:45   0  37.0 hours
4 2020-07-04 02:33:45   1  11.0 hours
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer.. one question I have is on the output .. for 2020-07-03 it should be actually 15:33:35.. I think now you are finding the difference between 2020-07-03 15:33:45 and 2020-07-02 10:33:45..  but it should be between 2020-07-02 10:33:45 and 2020-07-02 23:59:59 also between 2020-07-03 00:00:00 and 2020-07-03 15:33:45

Comment: I do find the differences between the dates, true. It is possible to further allocate the difference to each day. But what happens when there are two, three, .. days inbetween? Do you want to have a difference of 24 hours for each of these days?

Comment: If the dates are in the data then the split should continue... Else it shouldnot split... Like you have data for 9,10,11 dates... Then it comes to 14.. and you last data point on 11th is having 1 and first point on 14th is 0( they are adjacent in dataset).. but we should stop at 23:59:59 on 11th as the data is not continued on next day.. and on 14th it will start from first occurrence of 1